# jQuery appends list items closer together at each input submission

Tags: jquery, html, css

Position of the `<li>`(*input value*) and the `<div>`(*delete button*) is only correct after submitting the first input. At each other submission are these elements closer and closer together, which is not the desired behaviour. 
I'd like every input to be looking as the first one.

Here's the [Pen](https://codepen.io/patres/pen/xrgdKN).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="list-container">
    <ul class="list">
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
text-align: center;
list-style: none;
font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif; 
}

li {    
float: left;
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
}

.btnDel {
float: right;
font-family: 'Raleway'; 
width: 70px;
height: 20px;
border-radius: 15px;
border: 1px solid #F64747;
background-color: white;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
color: #F64747;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('input[name=listItem]').enterKey(function(){
    var toAdd = $('input[name=listItem]').val();
    $('.list').append('<li class="item">' + toAdd + '</li>', '<div class="btnDel">Delete</div>', '<br>')
```

Comment: What did you expect exactly ?

Comment: You're appending invalid markup. A comma in `append` means you're inserting the DIV and BR inside an UL.

Comment: you can use a div inside of li with specific width. And within this div you can add what do you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your are appending wrong structure. You should not use any other element as a direct child of ul.

I have updated your code here is new code and it is working great.

Here Some JS Modifications

```
// Form submit & Form clear function for Enter key press
    $('input[name=listItem]').enterKey(function(){
        var toAdd = $('input[name=listItem]').val();
        $('.list').append('<li class="item"><p>' + toAdd + '</p><div class="btnDel">Delete</div></li>')
    $('input[name=listItem]').closest('form').find("input[type=text]").val("")
    })

    // Form submit & Form clear function for button press
    $('#btnAdd').click(function(){
        var toAdd = $('input[name=listItem]').val();
        $('.list').append('<li class="item"><p>' + toAdd + '</p><div class="btnDel">Delete</div></li>')
    $('input[name=listItem]').closest('form').find("input[type=text]").val("")
    })
```

And Some CSS Modifications

```
li{ 
    clear:both;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
li>p{
  float:left;
}
li>div{
  float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because each succeeding todo-item in your case tries to float around preceeding.

The fast and nasty fix may be to add **clear:left** to **li**, see [updated pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XgpRaL).

```
li {    
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    ...
```

But actually you have to rework your markup - you should not insert anything except **li** inside **ul**.